# Chart in javascript doesn't change color

Tags: javascript, python, django, charts, apexcharts

I have a problem in javascript with building financial candlestick charts. I made a chart with apex.js and it displays the correct data where it should be but the color of the chart doesn't change, when the stock price is going up candlestick should be green when it goes down it should be red but on some stocks candlestick in always red and on some stocks it works fine. Here are the images, both charts use the same code but different data because it's different stock but that doesn't mean it should be displayed like this.
[image]

[image]

Here is code for chart:

```
<div id="chart">

    </div>
    <script>

        var options = {
            series: [{
                name: 'OHLC',
                data: [
                    {% for stock in stocks %}          
    {
                x: new Date("{{stock.date}}"),
                y: [Number("{{stock.open}}"), Number("{{stock.high}}"), Number("{{stock.low}}"), Number("{{stock.price}}")],
            },
            {% endfor %}
            ]
        },
    ],
        chart: {
            type: 'candlestick',                     
        },
        title: {
            text: '{{ticker}} Stock ',
                align: 'center'
        },
        yaxis: {
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
        chart.render();
    </script>
```

I am using Django in the backend so here is a function that returns chart data:

```
@login_required(login_url='stock:login')
def chart(request, ticker):
    stocks = Stock.objects.filter(ticker = ticker).order_by('date')
    context = {'stocks':stocks, 'ticker':ticker}
    return render(request, 'stock_app/chart.html', context)
```

I am struggling with this for a few days and didn't even make slight progress, can anyone help me or at least tell me where the issue could be I would be really thankful. I check the database, data, and code, switched a few services, and used chart.js, plotly, and a few others and it's always the same issue. I also checked data on yahoo finance for stocks that are not displayed correctly and data is correct.

Comment: Please also provide an excerpt of the problematic dataset and the working dataset (ideally from the same timeframe with the same size) to allow for better comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help I found out what was the problem. The close price was misconfigured by the API provider so the close price was higher by a few cents than the low price which caused the error

Comment: Thanks for your question! Next time, if you do not have confidentiality issues, please provide your dataset. It will be easier to help you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you replace libraries and the issue prevails, the problem cannot be the library; instead the provided data might contain wrong information that lead to an indifferent resolution on your chart.

I see that you don't specify the candlestick colors specifically inside the specification, so this might be worth a shot, albeit its probably only basis configuration:

```
  plotOptions: {
    candlestick: {
      colors: {
        upward: '#3C90EB',
        downward: '#DF7D46'
      }
    }
  }
```

https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/candlestick/

However, if the problem is the data itself you should rather provide an excerpt of a faulty stock and also one where it works just fine. Without stepping too deeply into Apex, maybe High/Low or Opening/Closing is mixed or wrong.

Comment: I tried changing the color of the chart earlier but it didn't solve the problem, I will check one more time data in DB.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say what is going on without your dataset. However, I suspect a lack of configuration of your `xaxis`, especially because your time scale does not seem consistent. Could you put this in your options and see what happens?

```js
xaxis: {
  type: 'datetime'
},
```

You can also have a **category axis** with a **candlestick chart**, but you may need extra configuration (a **formatter**, for example...). See this official demo: [Category x-axis – ApexCharts.js](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/candlestick-charts/category-x-axis/)

I paste the example below for convenience.

```js
var options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'candle',
    data: [
      {
        x: new Date(1538778600000),
        y: [6629.81, 6650.5, 6623.04, 6633.33]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538780400000),
        y: [6632.01, 6643.59, 6620, 6630.11]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538782200000),
        y: [6630.71, 6648.95, 6623.34, 6635.65]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538784000000),
        y: [6635.65, 6651, 6629.67, 6638.24]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538785800000),
        y: [6638.24, 6640, 6620, 6624.47]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538787600000),
        y: [6624.53, 6636.03, 6621.68, 6624.31]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538789400000),
        y: [6624.61, 6632.2, 6617, 6626.02]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538791200000),
        y: [6627, 6627.62, 6584.22, 6603.02]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538793000000),
        y: [6605, 6608.03, 6598.95, 6604.01]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538794800000),
        y: [6604.5, 6614.4, 6602.26, 6608.02]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538796600000),
        y: [6608.02, 6610.68, 6601.99, 6608.91]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538798400000),
        y: [6608.91, 6618.99, 6608.01, 6612]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538800200000),
        y: [6612, 6615.13, 6605.09, 6612]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538802000000),
        y: [6612, 6624.12, 6608.43, 6622.95]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538803800000),
        y: [6623.91, 6623.91, 6615, 6615.67]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538805600000),
        y: [6618.69, 6618.74, 6610, 6610.4]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538807400000),
        y: [6611, 6622.78, 6610.4, 6614.9]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538809200000),
        y: [6614.9, 6626.2, 6613.33, 6623.45]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538811000000),
        y: [6623.48, 6627, 6618.38, 6620.35]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538812800000),
        y: [6619.43, 6620.35, 6610.05, 6615.53]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538814600000),
        y: [6615.53, 6617.93, 6610, 6615.19]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538816400000),
        y: [6615.19, 6621.6, 6608.2, 6620]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538818200000),
        y: [6619.54, 6625.17, 6614.15, 6620]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538820000000),
        y: [6620.33, 6634.15, 6617.24, 6624.61]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538821800000),
        y: [6625.95, 6626, 6611.66, 6617.58]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538823600000),
        y: [6619, 6625.97, 6595.27, 6598.86]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538825400000),
        y: [6598.86, 6598.88, 6570, 6587.16]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538827200000),
        y: [6588.86, 6600, 6580, 6593.4]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538829000000),
        y: [6593.99, 6598.89, 6585, 6587.81]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538830800000),
        y: [6587.81, 6592.73, 6567.14, 6578]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538832600000),
        y: [6578.35, 6581.72, 6567.39, 6579]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538834400000),
        y: [6579.38, 6580.92, 6566.77, 6575.96]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538836200000),
        y: [6575.96, 6589, 6571.77, 6588.92]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538838000000),
        y: [6588.92, 6594, 6577.55, 6589.22]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538839800000),
        y: [6589.3, 6598.89, 6589.1, 6596.08]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538841600000),
        y: [6597.5, 6600, 6588.39, 6596.25]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538843400000),
        y: [6598.03, 6600, 6588.73, 6595.97]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538845200000),
        y: [6595.97, 6602.01, 6588.17, 6602]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538847000000),
        y: [6602, 6607, 6596.51, 6599.95]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538848800000),
        y: [6600.63, 6601.21, 6590.39, 6591.02]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538850600000),
        y: [6591.02, 6603.08, 6591, 6591]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538852400000),
        y: [6591, 6601.32, 6585, 6592]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538854200000),
        y: [6593.13, 6596.01, 6590, 6593.34]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538856000000),
        y: [6593.34, 6604.76, 6582.63, 6593.86]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538857800000),
        y: [6593.86, 6604.28, 6586.57, 6600.01]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538859600000),
        y: [6601.81, 6603.21, 6592.78, 6596.25]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538861400000),
        y: [6596.25, 6604.2, 6590, 6602.99]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538863200000),
        y: [6602.99, 6606, 6584.99, 6587.81]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538865000000),
        y: [6587.81, 6595, 6583.27, 6591.96]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538866800000),
        y: [6591.97, 6596.07, 6585, 6588.39]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538868600000),
        y: [6587.6, 6598.21, 6587.6, 6594.27]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538870400000),
        y: [6596.44, 6601, 6590, 6596.55]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538872200000),
        y: [6598.91, 6605, 6596.61, 6600.02]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538874000000),
        y: [6600.55, 6605, 6589.14, 6593.01]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538875800000),
        y: [6593.15, 6605, 6592, 6603.06]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538877600000),
        y: [6603.07, 6604.5, 6599.09, 6603.89]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538879400000),
        y: [6604.44, 6604.44, 6600, 6603.5]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538881200000),
        y: [6603.5, 6603.99, 6597.5, 6603.86]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538883000000),
        y: [6603.85, 6605, 6600, 6604.07]
      },
      {
        x: new Date(1538884800000),
        y: [6604.98, 6606, 6604.07, 6606]
      },
    ]
  }],
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: 'candlestick',
  },
  title: {
    text: 'CandleStick Chart - Category X-axis',
    align: 'left'
  },
  annotations: {
    xaxis: [
      {
        x: 'Oct 06 14:00',
        borderColor: '#00E396',
        label: {
          borderColor: '#00E396',
          style: {
            fontSize: '12px',
            color: '#fff',
            background: '#00E396'
          },
          orientation: 'horizontal',
          offsetY: 7,
          text: 'Annotation Test'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
      formatter: function(val) {
        return dayjs(val).format('MMM DD HH:mm')
      }
    }
  },
  yaxis: {
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1.11.7/dayjs.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```